# I'm having difficulty calculating time differences in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, time

[Layout of Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O90oA.png)

I am trying to build a program that calculates times differences in minutes. I do this by subtracting the start time from the finish time. I have four text boxes, two of which are for the time unit of hours (h), and the other two are for minutes (m).

`a` is the starting time in hours and `c` is the finish time in hours. They are being multiplied by 60 to convert the hours to minutes. I want to calculate the time difference between 5:40pm and 7:15pm but some how end up with 567 when the answer should be 95.

This is not a homework task, I'm a lazy learner driver in Australia who wants to create a simple program that calculates the time of a journey in minutes.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Calc
    Dim Product
    Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter.Click
    a = Val(TextBox1.Text) * 60
    b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    c = Val(TextBox3.Text) * 60
    d = Val(TextBox4.Text)
    Product = (c - a + d - b)
    Time.Text = ("Driving Time: " & Product)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You should create two `TimeSpan` values and then subtract one from the other. You can then get the appropriate property value(s) from the resulting `TimeSpan`, e.g. `TotalMinutes`.

Comment: I get 95. This code should work in limited cases where both the start and end times are both AM or both are PM and both are in the same day.

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't going to post this but I couldn't let the use of `TimeSerial` by Dy.Lee go unanswered.  This code uses reasonable variable names, uses the correct type for time periods, i.e. `TimeSpan`, and also compiles with `Option Strict On`, which it should pretty much always be.  I'd get rid of that `Val` usage too but I couldn't be bothered here.

```
Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter.Click
    Dim startHours = CInt(Val(TextBox1.Text))
    Dim startMinutes = CInt(Val(TextBox2.Text))
    Dim endHours = CInt(Val(TextBox3.Text))
    Dim endMinutes = CInt(Val(TextBox4.Text))

    Dim startTime As New TimeSpan(startHours, startMinutes, 0)
    Dim endTime As New TimeSpan(endHours, endMinutes, 0)
    Dim timeDifference = endTime - startTime

    Time.Text = ("Driving Time: " & timeDifference.TotalMinutes)
End Sub
```

EDIT: It also declares variables in the appropriate place, i.e. in the method they're being used in.  If you're using those same variables elsewhere then you'd have to stick with fields but I'm guessing that you're not doing so.

EDIT: Here's a version without the dodgy `Val` calls and some proper validation.  You could combine all the `If` statements into one but separating them allows you to display different messages based on the type of issue.

```
Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter.Click
    Dim startHours As Integer
    Dim startMinutes As Integer
    Dim endHours As Integer
    Dim endMinutes As Integer

    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, startHours) AndAlso
       Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, startMinutes) AndAlso
       Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, endHours) AndAlso
       Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, endMinutes) Then
        If startHours < 24 AndAlso
           startMinutes < 60 AndAlso
           endHours < 24 AndAlso
           endMinutes < 60 Then
            Dim startTime As New TimeSpan(startHours, startMinutes, 0)
            Dim endTime As New TimeSpan(endHours, endMinutes, 0)

            If startTime < endTime Then
                Dim timeDifference = endTime - startTime

                Time.Text = ("Driving Time: " & timeDifference.TotalMinutes)
            Else
                'Notify user of invalid input.
            End If
        Else
            'Notify user of invalid input.
        End If
    Else
        'Notify user of invalid input.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney, thanks for your answer. I tried it and still received 567. :(

Comment: If you're getting the wrong output then you're using the wrong input.  Your inputs should be "17", "40", "19" and "15" respectively.  Are they?  Have you actually debugged your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code line by line and examined the state of the application at each step? If not, do that now. If you don't know how, now is the time to learn. Debugging is a critical skill for any developer and you really ought to have done it before even posting here.

Comment: I just did that and got 141. I literally have a total of 21 lines of code which also includes comments and whitespace. I can't see anything wrong with the code at all. The math checks out in my head. I even used a calculator on my phone and got 95.

Comment: What does this mean "Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled." ??? Is it possibly a setting that affects calculations?

Comment: @Shankz  You're not using the code provided here, then. Or your input is wrong. Also, using you original code (and Time format), the calculation should be `(c - a) - (b - d)` or `(endHours * 60 - startHours * 60) - (startMinutes - endMinutes)`.

Comment: Use the code I provided and step through it in the debugger. Use the debugger to check whether each `TextBox` contains the value you expect and then each of those `Integer` variables contains what you expect. If they do all contain what you expect then you can't possibly get the wrong result.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, your wish... ;-)

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I tried your new code and still got 567. How do I use the debugger to check the value of the textboxes? Nothing appears in autos, locals or watch 1. Do I manually have to add break points or something? I'm fairly new to this and the only sort of "debugging" I'd do is probably fixing build errors. Also, please don't think I'm wasting your time, that's the last thing I would want to do. I'm just getting really frustrated from receiving the same number regardless of what the code is.

Comment: @Jimi, there is nothing wrong with my calculations. If anything your's is wrong because the answer would be 65. There is clearly more than 65 minutes difference between 5:40pm and 7:15pm.

Comment: Well, the result of that calculation is 95, no matter if the Time is 17:40 and 19:15 or 5:40 and 7:15. Did you read what @Paul Hebert wrote in his last comment?

Comment: There are lots of places you can learn how to debug.  Just type "vb.net debugging" into a search engine and do some reading.

Answer (score 1):

@PaulHebert pointed out to me that I needed to swap around textbox 3 & 4 because I was treating the wrong fields as hours. The math had made sense in my head so I probably overlooked a rather simple yet inconvenient mistake. I want to thank everyone who tried to help :) Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Your math is wrong you are subtracting the hours and then adding them to the difference of minutes. You need to get the total number of minutes since midnight from each time and then subtract those. Then get the absolute value so you don't have negative minutes

```
Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Enter.Click
a = Val(TextBox1.Text) * 60
b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
c = Val(TextBox3.Text) * 60
d = Val(TextBox4.Text)
Product = Math.Abs((c +d) - (a + b))
Time.Text = ("Driving Time: " & Product)
```

End Sub

Comment: This is a fine example of why you should use meaningful names for things.  If the names of those variable actually described the variables then it would be quite obvious that the calculation made no sense, whereas reading `c - a + d - b` isn't really going to tell you anything about what that's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Also Paul Hebert, there is nothing wrong with my math and I even deleted what I had and used your method and still received 567. No matter how many brackets I use or what order I put the variables in, I still receive 567.

Comment: Damn, I had added a photo of the GUI of my program when I posted my initial question but it didn't show up. i'm 100% sure it would help to make sense of the variables and perhaps other relevant issues for some of you. EDIT: Just updated it now.

Comment: Figured it out you are treating the wrong fields as hours instead of 7 hours 15 minutes you have 15 hours 7 minutes 907 - 340 = 567. Just swap textbox 3 & 4. This is why proper field names are important

Comment: @PaulHebert, Thankyou so much it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
    Private Sub Enter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
          a = CInt(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) * 60
          b = CInt(Trim(TextBox2.Text))
          c = CInt (Trim(TextBox3.Text)) * 60
          d = CInt(Trim(TextBox4.Text))
          Product = (c + d) - (a + b)
          Time.Text = ( "Driving Time: " & Product)
   End Sub
```

Also make sure that the text boxes are properly arranged. Text box 1 should come first followed by the others.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work however what does CInt and Trim do?

Comment: CINT converts the text in the textbox to an integer value, and trim removes all whitespaces from the textbox.

Comment: thanks for the clarification :) Merry Christmas